# Can not add SharePoint hosted app to the page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have created a basic sharepoint hosted app using following microsoft tutorial.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx#Code

It contains a basic list and default page. After deployment the app is available in site contents and works fine when i click on it but i can not add the app on page.

It is not available in the apps when i tried to add it on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your requirement you will need to create Client Web Part in your SharePoint Hosted App. When you add Client Web Part in your SharePoint Hosted App solution and deploy it then you will find your App in **Insert >> App Part** ribbon. You can use the default page that Client Web Part provide or else you can give path of your existing page that you already have been created in your App while adding Client Web Part.

You can find detail regarding how to create SharePoint Hosted App with Client Web Part [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/08/01/how-to-build-a-sharepoint-hosted-client-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

**Updated**

If you are using SharePoint Provider Hosted App then in that case also the mechanism is same. You can add Client WebPart. You can find more detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt637896.aspx)

Let me know whether it solves your problem or need more assist.

Comment: Thanks Akash. Could you please suggest if the same will be applicable on provider hosted apps as well. I am facing the same on provider hosted app as well

Comment: Yes, you can. I updated my answer for Provider Hosted App as well

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the "Add-In Parts" functionality to add the this app to a page. Microsoft provides a tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921.aspx.