# SharePoint hosted app within the Host Web

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created a nice little SharePoint hosted app. When I launch the app, it brings me to the app domain and a dedicated page (default.aspx).

My question is, how do I embed this App within my Host web without getting redirected to the App web? I want to add multiple instances to different pages like I would as if it was a normal Web Part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement you will need an Client WebPart in your SharePoint Hosted App. And you can include Client WebPart on your SharePoint web page as an normal WebPart.

For more detail please refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183655/can-not-add-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-the-page/183660#183660) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create Add-in Parts or Client web parts inside SharePoint hosted apps. Then it can be added to any page in your host web , just like any webpart. See this post about [Add-in Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921.aspx)