# Sharepoint 365 Cant Add Web Part to Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365

I have read through several threads answering this exact question. However these threads relate to older SharePoint editions and am unsure if my inability to implement the solution is due to version differences or more likely my own incompetence.

I am using SharePoint online via Office 365. I am having trouble adding a custom task list app to a subsite. It simply does not appear. The thread below answers this question, but I can't work out where to put the code in the answer given:

[How to add apppart to a page on subsite? The app part is not available in the subsite, only on parent site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202377/how-to-add-apppart-to-a-page-on-subsite-the-app-part-is-not-available-in-the-su)

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add classic list (with template as "Tasks")? or you trying to add custom app developed using visual studio?

Comment: You can offer a screenshot about the web part.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am trying to add classic list (with template as "Tasks")

Comment: I have the exact same issue (XML error) and it’s driving me crazy. Is this even possible on SharePoint Online? Does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to display list from parent site in sub-site?

Displaying SharePoint Online lists to parent or sub-sites for your reference:

https://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites

Comment: Thanks Lisa thats really helpful. However I am getting the following XML error on this method when trying to finally add the list to the subsite:

The file you imported is not valid. Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML.